# Почему не удаляется только псевдокласс, а удаляются весь css документа?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
var ter = document.styleSheets[1]  

ter.deleteRule(.block__header::after)

console.log(.block__header::after)
```

Почему не удаляет его из документа css?

В консоли находит этот псевдокласс,  более того, если прогнать через цикл -  удаляет все css документа.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   ter.deleteRule(`.block__header::after`)
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно именно удалять, потому что создается, каждый раз новые правила и они копятся, потом страница лагает.

Comment: А зачем их удалять? Просто пройдитесь по ним и присвойте им `display: none` или `content: none;`

Comment: страница может тупить если вы используете animation в цыкле на псевдокласс, просто остановите анимацию...

Comment: потому что [параметром должен быть **index**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule)

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [описанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule):

```
stylesheet.deleteRule(index)
```

Параметр передаваемый в эту функцию - это index правила, которое нужно удалить.

```js
var ter = document.styleSheets[0];
console.log(ter.rules);
ter.deleteRule(2);
console.log(ter.rules);
```

```css
.block {
  color: red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.block::after {
content:"after";
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block::before {
content:"before";
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Ты же передаешь строку, что в конечном счете приводит к удалению правила с индексом `0`.

Если нужно удалять именно по тексту селектора - можно в цикле найти нужный индекс и удалить:

```js
function removeRuleBySelector(styleSheet, selector) {
  for (var i = styleSheet.rules.length; i-- > 0;) {
    if (styleSheet.rules[i].selectorText == selector) {
      styleSheet.deleteRule(i);
    }
  }
}

var ter = document.styleSheets[0];
removeRuleBySelector(ter, `.block::after`);
```

```css
.block {
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.block::after {
  content: "after";
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block::before {
  content: "before";
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```